# How do I read emails from specific outlook folder in my Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, outlook, email-client

I'm using Outlook as email client and want to access its information through a Delphi program.

I want to retrieve the subjects from all emails in a specific folder, which is a couple of levels deep with respect to the Outlook root. I can list the email items from the root folder, but not for other folders. My current code is

```
procedure TForm1.BtnListMailItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Outlook, NameSpace, MailRoot, Mail: OleVariant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  try
    NameSpace := outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
    MailRoot := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
    for I := 1 to MailRoot.Items.Count do
    begin
      Mail := MailRoot.Items(I);
      if (Mail.class = olMail) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Mail.Subject);
    end;
  finally
    Outlook := UnAssigned;
  end;
end;
```

I guess I'll have to replace

```
MailRoot := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
```

by something like

```
MailRoot := NameSpace.GetFolder('Outlook\Archive\Shopping');
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

---

**Edit**

I tried this (per Peter Wolf's comment)

```
MailRoot := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
    
MyFolder := MailRoot.Folders.Item('Archive').Folders.Item('Shopping');
Memo1.Lines.Add('Folder name is "' + MyFolder.Name + '"');
    
MyFolder := MailRoot.Folders['Archive'].Folders['Shopping'];
Memo1.Lines.Add('Folder name is "' + MyFolder.Name + '"');
```

Both forms of the assignment result in an error: "An object could not be found".
I also tried adding the top level:

```
MyFolder := MailRoot.Folders['Outlook'].Folders['Archive'].Folders['Shopping'];
```

but no avail.
(The folders do exist.)

Comment: What other types than `olMail` do you encounter? Why not listing all those you yet ignore? It could already contain [`olFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass). Which documentation did you consult so far?

Comment: @AmigoJack -- I changed my loop to check for other classes, and still only get 5 emails, no folders. I guess I'll have to change the parameter for GetDefaultFolder, but the documentation on learn.microsoft.com doesn't seem to give any clues. (olFolders doesn't work, for instance)

Comment: Use [Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folders?view=outlook-pia) interface instead - e.g.: `MailRoot.Folders.Item('Archive').Folders.Item('Shopping')`. Since you use late binding you can shorten it to: `MailRoot.Folders['Archive'].Folders['Shopping']`. Note that the call to item getter will throw an exception when you specify invalid folder.

Comment: @Peter -- Tried it, but no avail (see edit in my question). Thanks for your thoughts anyway.

Comment: Is there really an `Outlook` folder at `MailRoot` (Inbox?) level? You can check that by iterating folders in a loop `for Index := 1 to MailRoot.Folders.Count do MailRoot.Folders[Index].FolderPath ...`

Answer (score 3):

`GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` does not return the top level folder, it returns the Inbox.

If the folder in question is on the same level as the Inbox, you can go one level up and then one level down to that folder:

```pascal
inbox := GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
inboxPeer := inbox.Parent.Folders['Peer Folder Name'];
```

Or you can start with the `Namespace.Folders` collection - it includes all top level folders of all message stores in the profile and drill down from there:

```pascal
theFolder := NameSpace.Folders['user@domain.demo'].Folders['the folder name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.BtnListEmailsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Outlook, NameSpace, MyFolder, Mail: OLEVariant;
    I, N: Integer;
begin
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    try
        NameSpace := Outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
        MyFolder := NameSpace.Folders['Outlook'];
        MyFolder := MyFolder.Folders['Archive'];
        MyFolder := MyFolder.Folders['Shopping'];

        N := MyFolder.Items.Count;
        for I := 1 to N do
        begin
            Mail := MyFolder.Items(I);
            if (Mail.class = olMail) then
                Memo1.Lines.Add(Mail.Subject);
        end;
    finally
        Outlook := Unassigned;
    end;
end;
```

The GetDefaultFolder step is unnecessary. You can assign the NameSpace's 'Outlook' folder directly. From there you can walk through the required levels using the object's Folders['some subfolder'].